# Could not find function or function reference normalize

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to combine multiple indicators in one script in the Pine editor of Tradview.
Therefore I need to change the scale of the volume histogram.

I think the function of normalize is not working in the version of Pine I'm using but I can't find anywhere if this function has changed name.

```
study("Stoch RSI Mom")

//RSI
plot(rsi(close, 14), color =red, title = "RSI")

//Stoch
plot(stoch(close, high, low, 14), color=orange, title = "Stoch")


//Momentum added 10 multiplier for scale
plot(mom(close, 10)*10, color =#2962FF, title="MOM")

//Volume
plot(normalize(volume, -100, 100), style=histogram, linewidth = 4, color=orange, transp=50)
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Could not find function or function reference normalize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a `built-in` function called normalize.

It looks like the function you want is this:

```
// ————— When the scale of the signal to rescale is unknown (unbounded).
// Min/Max of signal to rescale is determined by its historical low/high.
normalize(_src, _min, _max) =>
    // Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
    // _src      : series to rescale.
    // _min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series.
    var _historicMin =  10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)
```

[Source](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another)

Comment: This did work however I did have to add the correct version to my pine script.
At the top it said:
'//@version=2' 
I changed this to 
' //@version=4' 

I've added the normalize function using the code @vituvius suggested. 
I cleaned up my code a little bit

Comment: I do have one question, is it possible not to normalize over the full historic min max. Just for example last year or 6 months?